# Как вызвать метод класса несколько раз. React

Tags: reactjs

Есть класс у которого есть 2 метода

```
class SomeClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    someMethod1(className) {
      return (<div className='{className}'></div>)
    }
    someMethod2(n) {
      for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        this.someMethod1(this.props.className);
      }
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div>{this.someMethod2(this.props.counter)}</div>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Я не могу понять, почему на выходе я получаю только один элемент который создан методом1;

```
<div>
  <div class="element></div>
</div>
```

Если я ожидаю, что метод2 в 'n' получит например 5 и создаст 5 элементов, что я не понимаю и где я могу об этом почитать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь визуализировать более одного элемента, поэтому необходимо вернуть массив элементов. Измените вторую функцию, например, так:

```
someMethod2(n) {
  const arr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr.push(this.someMethod1(this.props.className));
  }
  return arr;
}
```